# Animation is effecting every view even after calling commitAnimation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation

I am developing a Cocos2D game. On a stage a show a UIView giving users a list of tasks to perform. There are text fields which I move up or down using Animation. My code is below.

```
        [textField setFrame:CGRectMake(textField.frame.origin.x, textField.frame.origin.y, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height)];
        [inviteButton setFrame:CGRectMake(inviteButton.frame.origin.x, inviteButton.frame.origin.y, inviteButton.frame.size.width, inviteButton.frame.size.height)];
        [headingLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(headingLabel.frame.origin.x, headingLabel.frame.origin.y, headingLabel.frame.size.width, headingLabel.frame.size.height)];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [textField setFrame:CGRectMake(textField.frame.origin.x, textField.frame.origin.y-50, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height)];
        [inviteButton setFrame:CGRectMake(inviteButton.frame.origin.x, inviteButton.frame.origin.y-50, inviteButton.frame.size.width, inviteButton.frame.size.height)];
        [headingLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(headingLabel.frame.origin.x, headingLabel.frame.origin.y-30, headingLabel.frame.size.width, headingLabel.frame.size.height)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Problem is that even after user is done and he presses the cancel button to remove this view from the super view, every view including UIAlertView and other subviews appearing in my map after removing that view are effected by the animation i used to move text fields and label up or down. UIAlertView is using same Animation to show up and so is happening other subviews. Can anyone please tell me why this is happening?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `animationID` to a unique value in the `beginAnimations:context:` method.
[See the official doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/beginAnimations:context:)
Also this doc states:

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

Comment: i got the solution. Thanks basvk. I was actually doing a mistake. I was calling [UIView commitAnimations] before even setting the frame of my UI components.